# Android Mail application not working

Tags: java, android, email

I have this piece of code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;

public class EmailSender {

    public void sendEmail(String personId, GsmCellLocation location) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); // added this line
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", "*******");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "******");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator("*****", "*******"));

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        System.out.println("Port: " + session.getProperty("mail.smtp.port"));

        // Create the email addresses involved
        try {
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("*****@gmail.com");
            message.setSubject("Yes we can");
            message.setFrom(from);
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("****@gmail.com"));

            // Create a multi-part to combine the parts
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

            // Create your text message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText("some text to send");

            // Add the text part to the multipart
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Create the html part
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlMessage = "Person " + personId + " at location: " + location + " might be in trouble, please check! ";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlMessage, "text/html");


            // Add html part to multi part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Associate multi-part with message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Send message
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "username", "password");
            System.out.println("Transport: " + transport.toString());
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());


        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To send an Email to myself.

When I try to run it on my Android Device, it keeps saying this:

http://pastebin.com/C6vCuSke

So it appears something is going wrong with the importing of the mail.jar and Activation.jar files. Yet, I imported them correctly, and added them to the list at the Order and export tab, and it is working when I run it as a normal Java Application. Can anyone tell me what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the problem, I was appearently using a jar file that was damaged or corrupted in some way! Glad I found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've missed to export the jar containing the **java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable** interface.

I think that it's included in the **rt.jar** (included in the JRE). Probably it should be possible to export this to the apk, but it is quite heavy (that's the Java runtime!) and the number of methods may exceed the single apk limit (65536). So you should probably change the email library.